# Datepicker & Jinplace

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have [Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and it's working fine [please check jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/10kd3xon/).
Also I have [Jinplace JQuery plugin](https://bitbucket.org/itinken/jinplace/wiki/Documentation) and it's also working fine [please check jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/49e2tcjs/).
But I can not get them to work together, I mean put datepicker inside editable jinplace div [please check jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L14bbvx0/).

Code:

```
$('.editable').jinplace({
});
$.fn.jinplace.editors.birthday = {
    makeField: function(element, data) {
        // Create a label with a checkbox inside it.
        var input = $('<input id="datepicker">');
        return input;
    }
};
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            yearRange: "1900:2016",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
```

In this case Jinplace generate HTML code like:

```
<div class="editable" data-type="birthday">
<form action="javascript:void(0);" style="display: inline;">
<input id="datepicker2">
</form>
</div>
```

But input#datepicker appears in HTML only after clicking on div.editable and have not been listed in the html code before this click. Like this:

```
<div class="editable" data-type="birthday">
</div>
```

Please check jsfiddle links above for more info.
How can I get them to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your input does not exist when the datepicker is initialised. You will need to make the datepicker call, which is this code:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        yearRange: "1900:2016",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeYear: true
});
```

once the input is rendered on the dom using jinplace.

As far as jinplace's documentation goes I cant find an onload event, So I am not sure how to go about this, unfortunately. But looking at the source code and your example, this might work:

```
$.fn.jinplace.editors.birthday = {
    makeField: function(element, data) {
        // Create a label with a checkbox inside it.
        var input = $('<input id="datepicker">');
        return input;
    },
    activate: function (form, field) {
       field.datepicker({
            yearRange: "1900:2016",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeYear: true
       });
       field.focus();
    },
};
```

I haven't tested this. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to make this `$('#datepicker').on('click', function(){
   $(this).datepicker({
   yearRange: "1900:2016",
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
   changeYear: true
   });
  });` and this `function datepickerinit(){
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
   yearRange: "1900:2016",
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
   changeYear: true
  });
 };` with `<input id="datepicker" onfocus="datepickerinit()">` and it's all not working for me...

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible solution. You will need to do something along these lines.